# Runtime error for double dimensional vector

Tags: c++, vector, runtime

I have a problem using double dimensional vectors. I have declared the double vector as an extern in my header file and again (not as an extern) in my main.cpp file just before my main() call. I call upon a function to dynamically allocate memory to the double vector. The given code gives no compilation error. But at runtime if you access the vector, it gives a  Vector subscript out of range exception. I checked it using my debugger and found that the vector is allocated the memory in the function, but as soon as it comes back (out of the function scope) the vector size goes back to 0.
I have attached the code

color.h:

```
#ifndef __COLOR__
#define __COLOR__

class color{
        public :
        int r,g,b;

        color(void);
        color(int R, int G,int B);
    };
#endif
```

color.cpp

```
#include"color.h"
#include <iostream>

color::color(void){
    r=g=b=0;
}
color::color(int R, int G,int B){
    if(R<=1 && G<=1 && B<=1){
    r=R;g=G;b=B;
    }
    else{
    std::cout<<"Error in RGB values";
    }
}
```

header.h:

```
#ifndef __HEADER__
#define __HEADER__

    #include <iostream>
    #include <vector>

    #include "color.h"

    const int windowWidth=200;
    const int windowHeight=200;

    void function();

    extern std::vector <std::vector<color> > buffer;

#endif __HEADER__
```

color.cpp

```
#ifndef __COLOR__
#define __COLOR__

class color{
        public :
        int r,g,b;

        color(void);
        color(int R, int G,int B);
    };
#endif
```

main.cpp

```
#include "header.h"
std::vector <std::vector<color> > buffer;
void main(void){
    //myClass obj=myClass(1,4);

    function(/*obj*/);
    std::cout<<"HI";
            std::cout<<"vector : "<<buffer[0][0].r;  //VECTOR SUBSCRIPT OUT OF RANGE
    getchar();
}
void function(){
    std::vector <std::vector<color> > buffer (2*windowHeight, std::vector<color>(2*windowWidth));
    std::cout<<"HI";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your function call `function()` has no side-affect on variable `buffer` which is defined in main.cpp. So in your main function it tries to access it will cause undefined behavior.

If you intent to let `function()` modify the global `buffer` variable, you could let `function()` return the vector.

```
std::vector <std::vector<color> > function()
{
    std::vector <std::vector<color> > buffer (2*windowHeight, std::vector<color>(2*windowWidth));
    std::cout<<"HI";
    return buffer;
}

int main()
{
    buffer = function();
    std::cout<<"vector : "<<buffer[0][0].r; // now you should be fine to access buffer elements
}
```